# Automapper - Map setup from collection<double> failing

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, .net-6.0

I have a Automapper setup that was working on the v10 version but since i updated it to the latest v11, it wont work anymore. I have no clue what could be the issue. The source and destination file are both the similar. Hope someone can help me.

The message that pops up when automapper is starting is

```
Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method Rig.Commercial.Reservation.Contract.V1.Generic.GeoJson.GeojsonPoint get_Item(Int32)' (Parameter 'property')
```

This is the map setup that i have in my profile:
`CreateMap<GeojsonPoint, Contract.V1.Generic.GeoJson.GeojsonPoint>().ReverseMap();`

Objects:

Source

```
    /// <summary>Geojson Coordinate</summary>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.5.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class GeojsonPoint : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<double>
    {
    
    }
```

Destination

```
/// <summary>
///  GeoJson coordinate
/// </summary>
[GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.5.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
public class GeojsonPoint : Collection<double>
{
}
```

Stacktrace

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreatePropertyMapFunc(MemberMap memberMap, Expression destination, MemberInfo destinationMember)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateAssignmentFunc(Expression createDestination)
   at AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.CreateMapperLambda(HashSet`1 typeMapsPath)
   at AutoMapper.TypeMap.Seal(IGlobalConfiguration configurationProvider, HashSet`1 typeMapsPath)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Seal()
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration..ctor(MapperConfigurationExpression configurationExpression)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_2(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__12_3(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Rig.Commercial.Reservation.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider apiVersionDescriptionProvider, ILogger logger) in C:\9292 Source\Git\Rig.Commercial.Reservation\Rig.Commercial.Reservation\Startup.cs:line 117
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsightsStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutoRegisterMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.HostingStartup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.HostingStartup.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
```

Comment: But what would such a map actually do? It seems those classes are just some collections. You don't need a map for that, check https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html.

Comment: GeojsonPoint is part of an parent object called GeoJsonLine which is a Collection of GeojsonPoint. I thought the mapper needed these setups?

Comment: what are the odds, I am facing exact same issue with version 11.0.0 . Will try to downgrade and see if that helps.

Comment: For me a downgrade fixed everything.

Comment: No, it didn't :) There is no reason to have those mappings for collections, unless they have other properties you didn't show here. But then you're not treating them as collections, which is even more confusing. Either way, the mappings make no sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason it breaks is because of a breaking change in version 11:

> C# Indexers (Item property)
> These used to be ignored by default, but that’s expensive and most types don’t have them. So you have to explicitly ignore them. Globally, with ShouldMapProperty or GlobalIgnores, or per member.

This means the internal property of an collection 'Item' is automaticly added to your mapping. You can fix it by adding `.ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore());` to your mapping.

In your case your mapping would be:

```cs
   CreateMap<GeojsonPoint, Contract.V1.Generic.GeoJson.GeojsonPoint()
     .ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore())
     .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: But why have that map? It doesn't seem to do anything useful. Why not write `ConvertUsing(s=>default)` or smth similar?

Comment: You need to add the Map because 'custom' collections are not added automaticly. I have tested this today and you can read more about it here: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html 

I don't know why Joris needs a custom collection, but note that his class is partial, so the custom behavior can be added somewhere else. In my case i need to extend an List<T> because we need our own json serialization because a bad json + we force lower key values so we have overriden the setter of `this[string name]`

Comment: A map for a list is _useless_ without a type converter. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: This has been confusing me for a couple of hours. I knew there was a breaking change upgrading from 7 to 11, but I just found out why now. +1

Answer (score 1):

My .NET Core 2.2 app had improper mapping for Lists and it threw an error in .NET 7 with the same stacktrace and message. Removing it resolved the error, and I already had the `CreateMap<Reference, ReferenceViewModel>` invocation

```
CreateMap<List<Reference>, List<ReferenceViewModel>>();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: So, just for my peace of mind, _removing_ the `List` mapping solved the problem, right? :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu was not able to tag you, removed the previous comment. Yes, it no longer throws this error and now I have to deal with other stuff - missing properties mapping (another incompatibility related to upgrade)

Comment: also is it possible that this was not valid in .NET Core 2.2 as well, but it did not ever bother programmers of my project, since AssertConfigurationIsValid was not called ? will need to check

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, but it was complaining about a lambda expression arguments.  The problem ended up being that one of my properties didn't have a valid map for its type.

I had

```
class ClaimDto {
  public VehicleDto Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
CreateMap<Models.xxx.Claim, ClaimDto>();
```

but I did not have

```
CreateMap<Vehicle, VehicleDto>();
```