# Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper, mapper

I'm using the last version of Automapper to map a model from the database that was created automatically via EF Core with my own model that has the same structure.

EF Core model :

```cs
public partial class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
    public string DateFormat { get; set; } = null!;
    public string TimeFormat { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<About> Abouts { get; set; } = new List<About>();
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
    public virtual ICollection<PostsTranslation> PostsTranslations { get; set; } = new List<PostsTranslation>();
}
```

My own model:

```cs
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

    public string DateFormat { get; set; } = null!;
    public string TimeFormat { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

But I have get this error:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'DatabaseProvider.Models.Language get_Item(Int32)' (Parameter 'property')

Automapper code:

```cs
public class MapperConfig
{
    public static Mapper InitializeAutomapper()
    {
        //Provide all the Mapping Configuration
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
cfg.CreateMap<API.Language, DB.Language>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.FullName))
    .ForMember(d => d.Abbreviation, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Abbreviation))
    .ForMember(d => d.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
    .ForMember(d => d.DateFormat, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DateFormat))
    .ForMember(d => d.TimeFormat, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.TimeFormat));

cfg.CreateMap<List<API.Language>, List<DB.Language>>();

cfg.CreateMap<DB.Language, API.Language>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
    .ForMember(d => d.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.FullName))
    .ForMember(d => d.Abbreviation, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Abbreviation))
    .ForMember(d => d.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
    .ForMember(d => d.DateFormat, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DateFormat))
    .ForMember(d => d.TimeFormat, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.TimeFormat));

cfg.CreateMap<List<DB.Language>, List<API.Language>>();
        });
        //Create an Instance of Mapper and return that Instance
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        return mapper;
       }
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
private readonly Mapper _mapper;
private readonly DatabaseConnector _connector = new();
private readonly ILogger<DatabaseController> _logger;

public DatabaseController(ILogger<DatabaseController> logger)
{
    _mapper = MapperConfig.InitializeAutomapper();
    _connector = new DatabaseConnector();
    _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet("GetLanguages")]
public IEnumerable<Language> GetLanguages()
{
    var dbList = _connector.Get<DB.Language>();
    var list = _mapper.Map<List<DB.Language>, List<Language>>(dbList);

    return list;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you please add the query you are using to get the `Language` model from the database?

Comment: @MernaMustafa, I used this:

Scaffold-DbContext “Host=localhost;Database=ToDoManager;Username=DBUsername;Password=DBPassword” Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -OutputDir Models

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the code that actually throws the exception. There's no running code in the question.

Comment: @GertArnold, no problem, I changed the code

Comment: Is this really all there is? It's not clear why AutoMapper complains about an indexer. Is there another `partial` part of `Language`?

Comment: @GertArnold, yes, that's all to understand. I have problem with mapping. If I will add this: .ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap(). 
I will get error related with `name` param
Language class is completly full here

Comment: Well, no, it's not all we need to understand what's going on. Now it appears that you have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71211119/861716) and already knew about it. It's pretty essential to know this and to see *exactly* what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If u have problem with "Item" or with "name" properties, just add this lines to the configuration of your mapper:

```
cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("Item");
```

It will fix your problems. And remember! Don't map lists, map only single items between each other!

Comment: You don't need `MapFrom` when the properties have the same name. Once you removed the silly list maps, you can probably remove the ignore for `Item`.

Comment: Your question still doesn't show why you had this issue in the first place.

Comment: @GertArnold He had those `List` maps and `List` has `Item`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Sure, but it's not obvious that AM tries to map the indexer. Many people won't immediately understand where an "Item" property is involved.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it seems fair :) I mean, after all these years, maps for lists, really?